# Identify ant-like pests under rock

Tags: pests

I turned up a rock just outside my house in the garden and found these ant-like creatures.  Are these termites or ghost ants or what?

[image]

And see the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCdWw90XL8k&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: +1 for the video: looks like another episode of the Ant Channel

Comment: You said they were pests. What are they pests to?

Comment: @Shule - Well if they are termites they are pests to my house.  If they are ants they are pests to my family as they may bite us.

Comment: If you want to know what kind of specific type of ant this is you can submit a question to http://www.antweb.org/antblog/ I did in the past and they were very helpful although I think you'll need a more close up photo.

Answer (score 4):

By the speed they were moving in your video, these are ants, not termites (which are slow movers). If you can get an upclose look at a specimen, here are some things to look for, that are easy to see:

- **Ants** have a narrow waist, clearly separating the thorax from the abdomen. Ants also have an elbow bend in their antennae.
- **Termites** have a nearly fused abdomen and thorax, and appear to have only two body segments. Termites also have straight antennae.

If these are termites, you may want to get your house/other wooden structures checked for damage. Most likely though, they're just after what cellulose they can find out in the yard. Termites are everywhere in nature, and are usually not a pest.

I think they are ants. If so, they probably aren't real pests. The only way ants are pests in the garden (usually) is by ant farming aphids, etc, making hills in lawns, and some that cut leaves. Most of them are just scavengers, or small hunters, and can even be beneficial that way.

Comment: I would add that if they are fire ants then they definitely qualify as pests. Those nasty buggers.